Why is there an overestimation in the PimlicoFeeEstimator in the relay-kit and Entry Point 0.7
Why is there a buffer added into callGasLimit, verificationGasLimit and preVerificationGas in the PimlicoFeeEstimator in the relay-kit ?
What's the reasoning?
https://github.com/safe-global/safe-core-sdk/blob/main/packages/relay-kit/src/packs/safe-4337/estimators/PimlicoFeeEstimator.ts#L21
I have been testing and saw very high fees.
In part because of this and also because the SDK supports only the 0.6 Entry Point.
I'm also wondering if the SDK will soon support the 0.7 EntryPoint?
We saw considerable differences in the fees calculation compared to the 0.6
